# How to trigger action when scrolling in UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am writing a small app about display images from a news website. Let say there are plenty of images. But each time it loaded, I just want to load 3 images and then display them on the screen. Only when the user scroll left to right, then it continues loading 3 more images.

How can I trigger that action when I scroll?

Please help me out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can implemente the UIScrollView delegate, it has some methods for what you want to achieve:

[UIScrollView delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

For example:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```